# Can I create an object factory for a templatized class

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on a library which creates a template base class and want to be able to let the implementers tell the base class how to create them making the base class as object factory
The base class actually has a lot of template parameter of type boolean and integer but have added only one for simplicity. The idea is to only add the code to the binary when the boolean is set to avoid branching here

```
template <bool Absolute>
class Abstract {
public:
    Abstract() : value_(0.0) {}
    virtual ~Abstract() {
    }

    void Calculate() {
        if(Absolute) {
            CalculateOnTrigger();
        }
    }
private:
    double value_;

    virtual void CalculateOnTrigger() = 0;
};
```

What is the best way to make this class control the object creation based on a configuration {I read an xml file from a manager and then instantiate each derived class based on the traits }

I created a simple prototype using the simple implementation as explained here

http://www.mass-communicating.com/code/2013/05/01/generic_factories_cpp.html

It does not work as soon as I add a template to this base class and gives me all kind of issues.

Any example explaining the same will be highly appreciated

---

To give more color

Abstract with true

```
template <bool Absolute>
class Abstract {
public:
    Abstract() : value_(0.0) {}
    virtual ~Abstract() {
    }

    void Calculate() {
        CalculateOnTrigger();
    }
private:
    double value_;

    virtual void CalculateOnTrigger() = 0;
};
```

Abstract with false

```
template <bool Absolute>
class Abstract {
public:
    Abstract() : value_(0.0) {}
    virtual ~Abstract() {
    }

    void Calculate() {
    }
private:
    double value_;

    virtual void CalculateOnTrigger() = 0;
};
```

This compiler optimization will save me loads of branching reducing latency

Comment: I want to let the compiler know at compile time that the value will always be true or false so that it does optimizations on it {Avoid branching at runtime} I actually have a lot of boolean configurations which have similar use at runtime <A lot of if (bool) than do that> which I already know when I instantiate the class.

Comment: Template parameters are evaluated at compile time.
For setting an flag (Absolute) from an XML you should use a member variable.

Comment: I do not want to call it a property and rather a trait of the concrete class which knows at instantiation time that it will never use that statement inside an if or will never use it throughout the lifetime of that object. I should be able to do it using templates to avoid checking that property at runtime in a critical path when I already know it will always be true or false

Comment: Added my thought process further to actually explain the advantage

Comment: Checking a bool at runtime is 'fast enough'.

If you want to do it at compile time you have to instanciate all possible combinations, put them in a list and search for the right one, corresponding the XML confgiuration. This is a lot more overhead.

Use templates when they are appropriate.

(If you consider about checking a bool at runtime, you have to know that virtual function also have runtime overhead!)

Comment: This seems like an example of premature optimization.  Modern branch predictors are extremely good and checking a branch has virtually no cost.

Comment: It *could be* a premature optimization.. it probably is. But just a reminder: branch prediction is only half of the story, first you have to retrieve the boolean. And memory is... slow.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Calling a function through a vtable is much more expensive than branch prediction or even fetching the `bool` from memory.

Comment: @Jason: and even that is considered a fast operation, and most people wouldn't worry about it (and then some do, because for some parts of their code even that is too much). But to get back your reasoning, `Calculate` isn't virtual. And if that boolean is false most of the time you won't incur much vtable call costs. But with the current approach you'll  abuse the memory cache just to get 1 bit(!). Nice abstractions like OO sometimes kill performance, but it's impossible to know whether it's something worth optimizing in the OP's code because... well, we virtually don't know anything about it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Cache prediction and pipelining will most likely hide the `bool` fetch cost as well.  Without any profiling information, at best it's a guess.

Comment: I have at least 50+ implementers with at least 10+ boolean in the critical path of every event. I should be able to implement it if it is possible so if someone can come up with a suggestion on how to do it then it would be helpful. unless someone says that it is theoritically not possible, I would like to hear for suggestions around the same.

Comment: @Jason: Who knows... It's not even a guess, it's just a *possibility*. I think we all agree that the OP is probably prematurely optimizing.

Comment: @Trying_to_get_there: As mentioned before, you can instantiate *all* the templates then pick the right one at runtime. I did that with booleans on an image processing system in a quite tight loop, and it worked really well.... but understand this: we generally don't prefer to help others shoot themselves on the foot (in this case, to create an architectural nightmare they don't even need). So far I haven't seen a single good reason why you need all this *censored*.